# Connect SonarQube (4.5.4 ) with Gradle (2.1) throws HTTP 400

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, build.gradle, sonarqube-4.5, gradle-2

I want to connect Gradle (Version 2.1) with SonarQube (4.5.4 LTS), but there is this Exception

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':<myProject>:sonarAnalyze'.
> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:  http://localhost:9000/batch/

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.
```

Relating to this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866574/sonarrunner-with-gradle-fail-to-download-libraries-from-server) it shoud be possible, and [here](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3062) is maybe the Bug with the related workaround.

But how can I use it? Unpacking the zip into the Project and importing the lines from the build.gradle from the zip-file doesn't work for me :( (makes no difference).

The sonar-configuration in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "sonar"

sonar {
    server {
        url = "http://localhost:9000"
    }
    database {
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar"
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username = "sonar"
        password = <myPassword>
    }
}

apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'

sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property 'sonar.host.url', 'http://localhost:9000'
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

PS: Gradle and Sonarqube are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sonar Plugin is [deprecated](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sonar_plugin.html):

> You may wish to use the new Sonar Runner Plugin instead of this
>   plugin. In particular, only the **Sonar Runner** **plugin supports Sonar 3.4**
>   and higher.

Use the [Sonar Runner Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sonar_runner_plugin.html) only

```
apply plugin: "sonar-runner"

sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
        property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar"
        property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        property "sonar.jdbc.username", "sonar"
        property "sonar.jdbc.password", "<myPassword>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact the two SonarQube plugins part of the Gradle distribution are now deprecated. See the following official message from the Gradle team: https://twitter.com/gradle/status/613530568655966208. Only the new one directly maintained by the SonarSource team should be used : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Gradle