# Why sonar-runner 2.0 Fails to download libraries from server

Tags: sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5

I have recently upgraded **Sonarqube** from **4.0 to 4.5.1** and the builds which are using **sonar-runner 2.0** are getting failed now with the below error.
 it used to work fine earlier when sonarqube 4.0 was installed

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from server
at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.downloadBatchFiles(Bootstrapper.java:166)
at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.createClassLoader(Bootstrapper.java:89)
at org.sonar.runner.Runner.createClassLoader(Runner.java:229)
at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:151)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:84)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:56)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:9000/sonar/batch/
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1612)
at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:748)
at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.remoteContent(Bootstrapper.java:125)
at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.downloadBatchFiles(Bootstrapper.java:158)
... 5 more
 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Why do i get this error? 
 Isn't **sonar-runner 2.0** compatible with **SonarQube 4.5.1??** if yes,
Which sonar-runner version would you recommend ?
This answer [SonarRunner with gradle: Fail to download libraries from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866574/sonarrunner-with-gradle-fail-to-download-libraries-from-server) didnot help as i am not using gradle
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: We are using SonarQube 5.1 together with the _sonarqube_ gradle-plugin (instead of the old _sonar-runner_ plugin). The latter should no longer be used (at least for Gradle). However it worked fine for us. We only upgraded because of a hint when running the build.